# How to group CI and CD jobs on Gitlab Pipelines

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, cicd

I want to run CI jobs on merge request creation and run CI jobs again and CD jobs when the merge request is merged.

.gitlab-ci.yml:

```
stages:
  - build # Docker build
    rules:
      - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"
  - test # Docker run container for test
    rules:
      - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"
  - push # Docker push to AWS ECR
  - deploy # Docker run container
```

The build and test stages trigger a pipeline well when merge request is created but when merge request is merged push and deploy stage didn't triggered.

I tried with `$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "push" && $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_EVENT_TYPE == "merged_result"`condition but doesn't work

What are the rules check conditions for this behaviour ? Any idea?

Comment: have you read https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/job_control.html

Comment: Yes, I've read the docs but i can't find a condition for merge request merged

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED

Gitlab pipelines rules for build and test stages (Continuous Integration):

```
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event" && $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME == 'develop'
      variables:
        ENVIRONMENT: 'dev'
    - if: ($CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event" && $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME == 'stage') || ($CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "stage")
      variables:
        ENVIRONMENT: 'stage'
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event" && $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME == 'main' || ($CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "main")
      variables:
        ENVIRONMENT: 'prod'
```

Gitlab pipelines rules for push and deploy stages (Continuous Deployment):

```
rules:
  - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "stage"
    variables:
      ENVIRONMENT: 'stage'
  - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "main"
    variables:
      ENVIRONMENT: 'stage'
```

Take into account to set Develop, Stage and Main branches protected and prevent direct push to canonical branches and set Gitlab *Settings -> Merge requests -> Merge checks -> Pipelines must succeed* checked